# Using static keyword in definition vs declaration in C

Tags: c, static, declaration, extern, linkage

The following compiles fine, using `static` only during declaration of function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int a();

int a(){
 return 5;
}

int main(){
 printf("%d\n", a());
 return 0;
}
```

As a side note, same behaviour as above happens with `inline` functions, i.e only the declaration could have the keyword.

However the following fails, doing the same but on a variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int a;

int a = 5;

int main(){
 printf("%d\n", a);
 return 0;
}
```

Getting thew error:
`non-static declaration of 'a' follows static declaration`.

What is with the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This quote from the C Standard shows the difference )6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers)

> 5 If the declaration of an identifier for a function has no
>   storage-class specifier, its linkage is determined exactly as if it
>   were declared with the storage-class specifier extern. If the
>   declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and no
>   storage-class specifier, its linkage is external.

So a function looks like it has the implicit storage specifier `extern` (but it does not mean that it has the external linkage opposite to an object identifier that in this case has the external linkage).

Now according to the following quote

> 4 **For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier extern
>   in a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is
>   visible,31) if the prior declaration specifies internal or external
>   linkage, the linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the
>   same as the linkage specified at the prior declaration.** If no prior
>   declaration is visible, or if the prior declaration specifies no
>   linkage, then the identifier has external linkage

So the function has the internal linkage due to its initial declaration with the storage specifier static.

As for the identifier of a variable then

> 7 If, within a translation unit, the same identifier appears with both
>   internal and external linkage, the behavior is undefined.

The resume from the above cited quotes is the following. If a function has no explicitly specified storage class specifier `extern` then its linkage is determined by a prior function declaration (if such a declaration exists). As for an identifier of object then in this case it has the external linkage. And if there is a prior declaration of the identifier with the internal linkage then the behavior is undefined.